# Non-isomorphic matroids on 5 elements

Tags: examples-counterexamples, matroids

In Oxley's book **Matroid Theory** (2nd edition) on page 594 there is a table stating that there are 38 non-isomorphic matroids on 5 elements. [image]

I have found 34: 32 graphic matroids (whose possible associated graphs you find in the pictures above an below).

[image]

Two more are the uniform matroids $U_{2,5}$ and $U_{3,5}$.

This leaves 4 more non-isomorphic matroids I would like to see. Can someone point me in the right direction to find these missing 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 16 binary matroids on four elements, and one non-binary maroid $U_{2,4}$: the uniform matroid on four elements. You can expand $U_{2,4}$ in three standard ways to a matroid on five elements as follows.

Assume ground set $E(U_{2,4}) = \{1,2,3,4\}$. You can add another element $5$ as

1. non-parallel basis element, that is, you arrive at $U_{2,5}$ with set of bases $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\}\}$
2. as parallel basis element (e.g. parallel to 4), that is, you get the set of bases $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\}\}$
3. as loop element, that is, you get $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$ as set of bases

This gets you 3 further matroids in addition to the 32 binary ones you have already found. If you take duals of these 3 you get the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Matroids are graphic iff they don't contain any of the five forbidden minors listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_matroid#Minors_and_duality). All but one of those forbidden minors have more than five elements, so the six non-graphic matroids on 5 elements necessarily have $U_{2,4}$ as a minor. So you can easily find those four remaining matroids by starting with $U_{2,4}$ and adding or expanding an element appropriately.